# Log Of Target Variable Linear regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am working on a linear regression housing dataset.

I am taking the log of my target variable like

```
df['SalePrice']=np.log(df['SalePrice'])
```

Then I am taking the exponent of my outcome to compute the loss as

```
lin_mse = mean_squared_error(np.exp(housing_predictions), np.exp(y_test))
lin_rmse = np.sqrt(lin_mse)
```

I am getting a huge error. Earlier I was getting around 23 but after this I am getting 22723! Without taking np.exp i get 0.1 but I want to compare to my previous value. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Withouth investigating too much, isn't it normal that the log of the error is much smaller than the original error?

Comment: As we don't see all the code it can be anything... Are you sure that `y_test` has also been through the `log` operation? I think it would be easier if you would share the whole code. (The lines where `y_test` is created for instance)